# Blazing Hydra vs Arcane Hydra

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

What's the advantage of [Blazing Hydra](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/active/hydra) compared to [Arcane Hydra](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/active/hydra)?

It looks like they both do the same thing except that blazing hydra damage is a little lower and the damage is delayed by 3 seconds.

Looks like arcane hydra win.

Comment: well, the damage is pretty much 400% per second. And you pretty much fire and forget. Not bad. Splash damage.

Comment: the aoe is so small though, If I had an extra skill slot on my bar I'd probably bring it but as it stands, there are much better fire and forget skills (like blizzard).  Maybe if I had that wand that allowed 2 active hydras I'll revist the skill.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On paper, Blazing Hydra seems to lose out to Arcane Hydra as it does less damage and requires a longer period to do so.  However, there are a few situations where you'd be using it:

1. With 2.0, you can now have many more pieces of equipment that boosts a specific elemental damage (for example, [the Burning Axe of Sankis](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/the-burning-axe-of-sankis) can spawn up to 20% fire skills boost).  If you were a fire focused wizard, you'd prefer your hydra to do fire damage to take advantage of that boost.  With several pieces added together, you can obtain up to 80% or more boost to fire damage skills.
2. If you had the [Conflagration](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/passive/conflagration) passive, having your fire damage spread out over time lenghthens the effect.

In case you are wondering why blazing hydra over mammoth hydra, the reason is because the 130% weapon damage is *per head/shot*, so all 3 added together can total 390% weapon damage, which is far more than mammoth hydra (but mammoth can potentially affect more monsters).

Comment: Also, the mammoth hydra ground AoE stacks with itself.

Comment: @Sharlike the blazing hydra also stacks with itself.  So I'd say if you wanted higher focused damage, go with blazing hydra but if you want more general AOE damage, go with mammoth.

Comment: Interesting. I recently switched to Mammoth Hydra from Arcane Hydra and love it. It lays down huge columns of fire on the ground, is fire-and-forget, and seems to help a lot more with big groups. No scientific measurements here, just anecdotal.

Comment: Speaking of +fire damage gear, there is also the [Firebird's Finery level 70 Wizard set](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/firebirds-breast), which increases fire damage *and* makes enemies killed by fire explode with AOE damage.